# How to generate a route without question mark on FOSJSRoutingBundle

Tags: javascript, rest, symfony

Im confused, this is the documentation

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

> documentation -> 
>   Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 }); // will result in
>   /foo/10/bar

this is the route on the controller (has the prefix "superuser")

```
/**
 * @Route("/deleteuser/{userid}",name="suDeleteUserRoute",options={"expose"=true})
 * @Template()
 */
public function deleteUserAction($userid)
{
```

so I obviously want to generate a route that looks like this

```
server.com/superuser/deleteuser/76
```

but it generates a route with a question mark instead

```
server.com/superuser/deleteuser?id=76
```

This is how I generate the route on Javascript

```
Routing.generate('suDeleteUserRoute', { id: 76 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route uses the `userid` parameter but you are giving it the `id` parameter.

Try using `Routing.generate('suDeleteUserRoute', { userid: 76 });` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the route in `routing.yml` something like this:

```
super_user:
    path:      /superuser/deleteuser/{userid}
    defaults:  { _controller: BundleName:ControllerName:FunctionName }
    requirements:
      userid:     \d+
```

- Controller Name should be without suffix `Controller`
- Function Name should be without suffix `Action`

Comment: That would be `routing.yml` and not really relevant to the question.